# Poltergeist can't find the element sometimes

Tags: ruby, capybara, integration-testing, poltergeist

I am using phantomjs 2.1.1, ruby 2.3.1p112. Here is my code:

```
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist    
  page.find('input[type="submit"]').trigger("click")
  page.should have_content("#{user.email} created.")
```

This code works on chorme's and firefox's webdriver but doesn't work sometimes with poltergeist. I don't know why. Can any one help, please?

Comment: There is no way that code woks on chrome or firefox since since the driver for those doesn't support `trigger` (and you shouldn't be using `trigger` if doing testing anyway) .  Beyond that, to get any more help you need to provide the exact failure message you're getting and some example of the HTML you're trying to interact with - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry when i run with chrome or firefox i change trigger to clink funtion

Comment: Then you need to figure out why you need to use `trigger` with Poltergeist and fix that issue (which will probably fix your intermittent failures too).  `trigger` should be avoided as much as possible when testing apps (if just scraping pages it's fine) since it means your tests aren't actually doing what a user would do, and therefore have dubious value.

Comment: so what i should use instead of trigger can you tell me

Comment: i am testing with website page

Comment: You should be using `click` when testing - so `page.find('input[type="submit"]').click` or even better would be `page.click_button('the text of the submit button')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS is no longer being actively supported. Use Chrome Headless or another headless browser solution.

Comment: can you give me a key work about that headless browser

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. This is headless chrome: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md Another option I have come across is SlimerJS https://slimerjs.org/  Both of these have very good documentation on how to get started.